# Magento 2 Get last and first item from model collections

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, resource-model

I want to retrieve the last and first item from model collection in magento 2, in magento 1.9 i can simply retrieve it like this :

```
$lastItem = $collections->getLastItem();
$firstItem = $collections->getFirstItem();
```

is there a way i can do the same in magento 2, without using foreach loop like this:

```
$collections = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Module\Model\Test')->getCollection(); 
$i=0;
foreach($collections as $collection){
  if($i == 0){
    $firstItem = $collection;
    $i++;
  } else{
    $lastItem = $collection;
  }
}
```

Comment: `$lastItem = $collections->getLastItem(); and 
$firstItem = $collections->getFirstItem();` is not working?

Answer (score 5):

This is Tested Solution feel free to implement

```
$firstItem = $collections->getFirstItem();
$lastItem = $collections->getLastItem();

echo 'This First Record in Collection <br> ';

print_r($firstItem->getData());

echo '<br> This LastRecord in Collection <br> ';

print_r($lastItem->getData());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a for-each loop then you should use the below code to get First and Last Item.

For First Item, you can use an array of 0. e.g `$collection[0]`. This will give you the first element of your array.

For the Last Item, you can reverse the array and then use the array of 0. e.g

```
$col = array_reverse($collection);
$lastItem = $col[0];
```

hope this helps you.