# Magento 2.3: get latest post from table

Tags: magento2, database

[image]

I have a simple post table, how can I get lasted post in the phtml file.

Comment: Have you created Model and Collection file associated with that tables?

Comment: I did. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below statement for getting first item or last item

```
$firstItem = $collections->getFirstItem();

$lastItem = $collections->getLastItem();
```

$collection is the variable that contains the collection

Comment: I just need one last post.

Comment: what code you do to get the collection? please post the full code that you are do

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163985/magento-2-get-last-and-first-item-from-model-collections

Answer (score 0):

In a Block PHP file, constructor adds one argument (Dependency Injection) like below and store it in a class member variable.

> Block Method

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ModelNameFactory $modelNameFactory,    
    array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

//prepare a public method in your block to access your table collection.

public function getCollection(){

    $collection = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection()->setOrder('portfolio_id', 'DESC');
    return $collection->getSelect()->limit(1);

}
```

> ObjectManager Method

```
$objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION'); 
$result1 = $connection->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY portfolio_id DESC");

echo "<pre>";print_r($result1);
```

However, the $objectManager method will not recommended to use directly in phtml file.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thank you, but how to get content like name, image...etc in frontend.

Comment: You can get it by adding Block Method in your modules block class and call the getCollection() function in the phtml file with $block->getCollection();

You can check the data with echo "<pre>"; print_r($block->getCollection()); in phtml file